# java actionlisteners advice needed, Jmenuitems

Tags: java, actionlistener, jmenuitem

> "Firstly, add ActionListeners to each of the JMenuItem objects. For
>   example, when you select “Square” from the menu, the ActionListener
>   attached to the ‘Square’ menu item must create an instance of your
>   ‘Square’ class. These ActionListeners will be added as code within the
>   constructor of your MyFrame class."

Could someone please walk me through how to do this?

Once the square is selected i need to then use my Jslider to some how work the area of the square, (given that the jslider value is one side of the square)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as though this looks like homework, I won't give you the specifics, but just a guide...

Following through your instructions, you'll first need to create a class that `implements ActionListener`, and implement the 'actionPerformed()' method as described in the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

Then you're instructed that this should detect what was clicked, and then create the appropriate `Object`. So, as per the Square instruction of your question, your `actionPerformed()` method would do something like this...

```
JMenuItem clickedMenu = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Square")){
    Square square = new Square();
}
```

You would need to add additional `if-else` statements for the different menu items.

Finally, it says that you need to add the `ActionListener`s to your `MyFrame` class, so it should be something like this...

```
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Square");
menuItem.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

Its just a matter of following through your instructions 1 piece at a time. If you get stuck at any point, try referring to the Java API documentation, or search for help here on StackOverflow.

Comment: i understand that but how to i link the Square square = new Square(); to the square class? then the slider value to the Sqaure class?                                                             package assignment;

/**
 *
 * author b00560806
 */
public class ASquare extends MyShape {

    @Override
    public double computeBoundaryLength(double Length) 
    {
        thelength=(4*Length);
        return thelength;
    }

    Override
    public double computeArea(double Length) 
    {
        thearea=(Length*Length);
        return thearea;
    }
    
}

Comment: The Java tutorials have a guide on how to use JSlider: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html StackOverflow can't really provide you with a step-by-step walk through of how to do the entire thing (doing your homework for you?). That is off-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You need to at least make your own attempt first and we can help you fix problems.